OSError: exception. How to correctly call connectUsartBootloader() func (from CubeProgrammer_API C dll) by means of python ctypes?
I'm trying to use CubeProgrammer_API.dll in python to program STM32 microcontroller memory over USART interface.
In general, following operations shall be performed at the beginning:

Get list of available serial ports using getUsartList() call (it returns array of usartConnectParameters structures).
Start connection to target through USART interface using connectUsartBootloader() call (passing selected usartConnectParameters structure)

CubeProgrammer_API.h
typedef struct usartConnectParameters
{
    char portName[100];             /**< Interface identifier: COM1, COM2, /dev/ttyS0...*/
    unsigned int  baudrate;         /**< Speed transmission: 115200, 9600... */
    usartParity parity;             /**< Parity bit: value in usartParity. */
    unsigned char dataBits;         /**< Data bit: value in {6, 7, 8}. */
    float stopBits;                 /**< Stop bit: value in {1, 1.5, 2}. */
    usartFlowControl flowControl;   /**< Flow control: value in usartFlowControl. */
    int statusRTS;                  /**< RTS: Value in {0,1}. */
    int statusDTR;                  /**< DTR: Value in {0,1}. */
    unsigned char noinitBits;       /**< Set No Init bits: value in {0,1}. */
    char rdu;                       /**< request a read unprotect: value in {0,1}.*/
    char tzenreg;                       /**< request a TZEN regression: value in {0,1}.*/
}usartConnectParameters;

int getUsartList(usartConnectParameters** usartList);

int connectUsartBootloader(usartConnectParameters usartParameters);

So far I'm able to invoke getUsartList() function and receive correct array of usartConnectParameters structures.
script.py
from ctypes import *
dll = cdll.LoadLibrary(r'C:\Program Files\STMicroelectronics\STM32Cube\STM32CubeProgrammer\api\lib\CubeProgrammer_API.dll')

class usartConnectParameters(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("portName", c_byte * 100),  #  or c_char * 100
                ("baudrate", c_uint),
                ("parity", c_int),  # usartParity
                ("dataBits", c_ubyte),  
                ("stopBits", c_float),
                ("flowControl", c_int),  # usartFlowControl
                ("statusRTS", c_int),
                ("statusDTR", c_int),
                ("noinitBits", c_ubyte),  
                ("rdu", c_byte),
                ("tzenreg", c_byte)]

getUsartList = dll.getUsartList
getUsartList.argtypes = (POINTER(POINTER(usartConnectParameters)),)
getUsartList.restype = c_int
uartParam = POINTER(usartConnectParameters)()
uartCnt = getUsartList(byref(uartParam))

Unfortunately when I'm trying to invoke connectUsartBootloader() function with one usartConnectParameters structure from the list,
connectUsartBootloader = dll.connectUsartBootloader
connectUsartBootloader.argtypes = (usartConnectParameters,)
connectUsartBootloader.restype = c_int
connectUsartBootloader(uartParam[0])

I'm getting an exception:
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000
Can anyone point me in the right direction or provide some more info on this kind of errors?

Assuming usartParity and usartFlowControl are simple enumerations and c_int is correct, everything looks good.  Is the structure packed?  You could try adding _pack_ = 1 to the structure definition.  If you look at the fields of uartParam[0] do they look correct?  Also check sizeof(usartConnectParameters) in C vs. ctypes.sizeof(usartConnectParameters) in Python and make sure they match.
